# spaces and special characters update query doesnt work, html form with 50 input fields 47 are int no prob, 3 are text/strings prob

Tags: php, html, mysql

running MySQL version 5.5.22 here is my code, problems and attempted solutions.
I am real confused where and how to escape spaces and special characters for the 3 string fields. I have many years programming but only a month with PHP, I know I need to get used to PDO from recent searching.. I would like to get it working without PDO (starting over). Thats for the next project please.

The form is like this, it has 50 fields, all int except 3 strings including "comments"
If I remove the string fields everything works, so I have problems with spaces and special characters.  I also used almost the same code to run thru a createTable.php and it worked fine. Oh n fyi I am not worried about injection at all...secured in house network.

The submit page has this

This is used to autofill html form page with what is already in the database table 
//$Comments="\"" . $rows['Comments'] . "\"" ; // and it works.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
This is the code on the update.php.
Much of the commented things are stuff I've tried so far.
    ";
    $ID=$_POST['ID'];

```
//******* put this text on the html page *******************

echo "This is what your update table query string will look like. for record ID=" . $_POST['ID'];
echo "</p>" ;
echo "The ID, pagetitle and Submit have been removed.";
echo "<p><hr>" ;

//********** Prepare the string **************

$query_string = "";
//if not post ie someone got here without post
if ($_POST) {
  $kv = array();
//loop thru submitted field-value keys
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

// Trim pagetitle and Submit from string
if ($key == 'pagetitle' OR $key == 'Submit' OR $key == 'ID') 
    {   }
  //else {$kv[] = "$key"."="."$value".",";} //format and add to array
  else {$kv[] = "$key"."="."'"."$value"."'".",";} //format and add to array

            } //end of foreach statement
  $query_string = join($kv);
    } //create querystring from array
else {$query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; } //end of if post statement
?>
<?php
    $myqrystring="";
  //$myqrystring = '"UPDATE MyTable SET '.$query_string;
  //$myqrystring = $query_string;
$query_string = rtrim($query_string, ","); // Trim last comma from string
//$myqrystring = "\"" . $query_string . "\"";

//******* put string on the html page for review.***********

// put myqrystring on the html page for review.
//echo $myqrystring;
echo $query_string;
echo "<hr>" ;
echo "<p>" ;

//******* Update DataBase Table **************

$testquery_string="Area=400, PID=400,Comments='Filled by someone@somewhere.com'";
//,Comments=Filled by someone@somewhere.com   htmlspecialchars()  htmlentities()
//urlencode()  $safeHtml = htmlentities($evilHtml, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');'".$val2."'
//this works ,Comments='Filled by someone@somewhere.com' in $testquery_string
//$testquery_string=rawurlencode($testquery_string);//Does not work
//$testquery_string = htmlentities($testquery_string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');//Does not work
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","ireene","IEC");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
//mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable SET Area=10 WHERE ID= $_POST['ID']");
//mysqli_query($con,'myqrystring');
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable SET $testquery_string WHERE ID= $ID");
//$testquery_string works not $query_string $myqrystring
//mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable SET $query_string WHERE ID= $ID");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I get this back on the page for review, looks correct but doesn't work'
Area='400',PID='400',Comments='something'. The single quoted Area and PID does work.
So I hope to loop thru all fields doing the same fix without separating the 3 strings.

Thanks a million, 
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string)
```

escaping your values like that might fix your problem.

Comment: Nazca 
it looks like you mean change
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable SET $testquery_string WHERE ID= $ID");
to 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"UPDATE MyTable SET $testquery_string WHERE ID= $ID");
replacing the mysqli_query is that correct? or should it be in Prepare(build) the string before the query?

Comment: Nazca, I tried it there n didnt work...the $con makes me think thats what you mean

Comment: maybe I'll try to add the single quotes before the post in the form page for just those 3 string fields- 3 out of 50 won't be to bad, I'll let you know how that goes

Comment: Well after 2 days searching...stumbled on this http://www.php.net/addslashes, been there a hundred times, just not the right page...
Automagically add slashes to $_POST variables.

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $input_arr) {
        $_POST[$key] = addslashes($input_arr);
     }

it worked like a charm.. Thanks a million for the help.

Comment: awesome!  Sorry I couldn't help more =[ You should post your answer and accept it, just in case some one with the same problem ends up here.